# How to remove a service account key on GCP using Ansible Playbook?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible, service-accounts

I am using an Ansible playbook to run certain modules that create service accounts and their respective keys. The code used to generate this is as found on the Ansible documentation:

```
- name: create a service account key
  gcp_iam_service_account_key:
    service_account: "{{ serviceaccount }}"
    private_key_type: TYPE_GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS_FILE
    path: "~/test_account.json"
    project: test_project
    auth_kind: serviceaccount
    service_account_file: "/tmp/auth.pem"
    state: present
```

Now I am trying to remove the service account key, so I changed the state value from present to absent but that doesn't seem to do much, wanted to ask if I'm missing something or if there is anything else I could try?

Comment: `doesn't seem to do much`: can you please edit your question and elaborate on that one ? Did you run the playbook with `-vvv` to have more info for example ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it could be possible since I couldn't find [the module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/list_of_cloud_modules.html) on the ansible documentation, but in the [deletion for instance](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/gce_module.html)s examples, I see that after the absent state they use a tag for the deletion, it could be a way to do it for the SA. e.g.

state: absent
      tags:
        - delete

Other way that could be useful is to directly do the request to the [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#iam-service-account-keys-delete-rest), e.g.

DELETE https://iam.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[PROJECT-ID]/serviceAccounts/[SA-NAME]@[PROJECT-ID].iam.gserviceaccount.com/keys/[KEY-ID]

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that it works when changing `state` from `present` to `absent` in version 1.0.2 of the `google.cloud` collection.

I believe that you expect the file in `path: "~/test_account.json"` to be deleted but in fact the key is deleted on the service account in GCP. You will have to delete the file yourself after the task has completed successfully.